# SmartTV + Frameworks

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I have a pretty uncommon question (at least for me). I just started tapping into Samsung Smart-TV SDK. I was thrilled that plain JS, HTML5 and CSS works. 
Afterwards I had successes and failurs...

**Success:**

1) Using Bootstrap
2) Using jQuery

**Failures:**

1) Using AngularJS.

Throws an error as if I have not loaded modules into the app. **HOWEVER** the same code works locally and everything loads up just fine.

So...any thoughts why Samsuns Smart-TV emulator in Eclipse gives an error?

And maybe give some tips and tricks from your experience developing for SmartTV

Comment: I am pretty sure it is because of the jQuery version. When importing af loader script, it also loads an older version of jQuery: 1.4 regardless the already jQuery script that you have or not.

Comment: @JoséCabo Could you elaborate please? What's an "af loader script"? How can it load an older jQuery version if I include one in the index.html?

Comment: If you are importing this script: <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/af/2.0.0/loader.js"></script>

no matters the jQuery version you have imported that the jquery that it contains will override yours.

Comment: Please, check the jQuery version with jQuery.fn.jquery to be sure which version are you loading.

Comment: @JoséCabo oh ok, didn't know that. So if I fix that the issue should be fixed?

Comment: I do not know. I just stated that that problem with angular might be related with jQuery since it can use it. But it looks like. Try to execute the emulator and see what the error says.

Comment: I suggest you try to debug with consoleIo: https://github.com/nkashyap/console.io. As @José Cabo suggests, Samsung Smart TV´s loads its own jQuery, I don´t know much about Angular, but global $ var can be overriden by Samsung internal jQuery. Emulator does not work on my machine, I don´t know why.

Comment: @JoséCabo I just checked my index.html. I do not load **loader.js** as you mentioned above. Here's a screenshot of the loading process - http://i.imgur.com/z9F1N2m.jpg

Comment: @JoséCabo The jQuery version is 2.1.4. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @puro_nervio The jquery version is 2.1.4. So any suggestions what should I check now?

Comment: Did you check with console.io tool? It can give you more information if there is an error while loading the javascript in the TV screen.